# Best Practice for handling consecutive identical useFetch calls with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

Here's the `useFetch` code I've constructed, which is very much based upon several well known articles on the subject:

```
const dataFetchReducer = (state: any, action: any) => {
  let data, status, url;
  if (action.payload && action.payload.config) {
    ({ data, status } = action.payload);
    ({ url } = action.payload.config);
  }  

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_INIT':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        isLoading: true, 
        isError: false 
      };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: data,
        status: status,
        url: url
      };
    case 'FETCH_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true,
        data: null,
        status: status,
        url: url
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}


/**
 * GET data from endpoints using AWS Access Token
 * @param {string} initialUrl   The full path of the endpoint to query
 * @param {JSON}   initialData  Used to initially populate 'data'
 */
export const useFetch = (initialUrl: ?string, initialData: any) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<?string>(initialUrl);
  const { appStore } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log('useFetch: url = ', url);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    data: initialData,
    status: null,
    url: url
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Starting useEffect in requests.useFetch', Date.now());
    let didCancel = false;
    const options = appStore.awsConfig;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });

      try {
        let response = {};
        if (url && options) {
          response = await axios.get(url, options);
        }

        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // We won't force an error if there's no URL
        if (!didCancel && url !== null) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE', payload: error.response });
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, [url, appStore.awsConfig]);

  return [state, setUrl];
}
```

This seems to work fine except for one use case:

Imagine a new Customer Name or UserName or Email Address is typed in - some piece of data that has to be checked to see if it already exists to ensure such things remain unique.

So, as an example, let's say the user enters "My Existing Company" as the Company Name and this company already exists.  They enter the data and press `Submit`.  The Click event of this button will be wired up such that an async request to an API Endpoint will be called - something like this: `companyFetch('acct_mgmt/companies/name/My%20Existing%20Company')`

There'll then be a `useEffect` construct in the component that will wait for the response to come back from the Endpoint.  Such code might look like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!companyName.isLoading && acctMgmtContext.companyName.length > 0) {
      if (fleetName.status === 200) {  
        const errorMessage = 'This company name already exists in the system.';
        updateValidationErrors(name, {type: 'fetch', message: errorMessage});
      } else {
        clearValidationError(name);
        changeWizardIndex('+1');
      }
    }
  }, [companyName.isLoading, companyName.isError, companyName.data]);
```

In this code just above, an error is shown if the Company Name exists.  If it doesn't yet exist then the wizard this component resides in will advance forward.  The key takeaway here is that all of the logic to handle the response is contained in the `useEffect`.

This all works fine unless the user enters the same Company Name twice in a row.  In this particular case, the `url` dependency in the `companyFetch` instance of `useFetch` does not change and thus there is no new request sent to the API Endpoint.

I can think of several ways to try to solve this but they all seem like hacks.  I'm thinking that others must have encountered this problem before and am curious how they solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a specific answer to your question, more of another approach: You could always provide a function to trigger a refetch by the custom hook instead of relying of the `useEffect` to catch all different cases.

If you want to do that, use `useCallback` in your `useFetch` so you don't create an endless loop:

```
const triggerFetch = useCallback(async () => {
  console.log('Starting useCallback in requests.useFetch', Date.now());
  const options = appStore.awsConfig;

  const fetchData = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });

    try {
      let response = {};
      if (url && options) {
        response = await axios.get(url, options);
      }

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response });
    } catch (error) {
      // We won't force an error if there's no URL
      if (url !== null) {
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE', payload: error.response });
      }
    }
  };

  fetchData();

}, [url, appStore.awsConfig]);
```

..and at the end of the hook:

```
 return [state, setUrl, triggerFetch];
```

You can now use `triggerRefetch()` anywhere in your consuming component to programmatically refetch data instead of checking every case in the `useEffect`.

Here is a complete example:

[CodeSandbox: useFetch with trigger](https://codesandbox.io/s/usefetch-with-trigger-9copt)

Answer (score 0):

To me this slightly related to thing "how to force my browser to skip cache for particular resource" - I know, XHR is not cached, just similar case. There we may avoid cache by providing some random meaningless parameter in URL. So you can do the same.

```
const [requestIndex, incRequest] = useState(0);
...
const [data, updateURl] = useFetch(`${url}&random=${requestIndex}`);
const onSearchClick = useCallback(() => {
  incRequest();
}, []);
```

Comment: I found this article by Paul Cowan, and the subsequent comments, to be very enlightening: https://blog.logrocket.com/frustrations-with-react-hooks/

If you scroll down to the comment by `Ciprian` @3:15pm on Sept. 17th you'll see an approach similar to mine above, but one that works.

That said, the first comment by `Karen Grigoryan` was the most interesting of all.  In it, he explains that calling async functions directly from an event handler, is not a good approach in React.  I've tested this approach by setting a state variable that, itself, triggers a useEffect.  This seems to be best!